Patching default.xex for Xbox 360 games with IDA or Ghidra
I'm trying to patch the Perfect Dark Zero XEX to remove the 30 FPS cap with IDA but it gets "826CFB77: has no file mapping (original: 02 patched: 01)...skipping...". Can someone help me patch the XEX with IDA or Ghidra?
